# Twitter account for gaming.blogoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, twitter

I've been seeing the statistics for gaming blog this evening. It seems that all visitors come from chat rooms. (And some [blogoverflow.com](http://blogoverflow.com) today since Rebecca has been announcing it all day :D)

Would it be possible to use the @StackGaming twitter account to promote new posts on the blog?

Or would it be more ideal to create a new twitter account for this purpose?

We could then make it benefits the retweeting effect to bring up more visitors.

Some suggestions for it:

- @StackGamingBlog
- @GamingBlog
- @SEGamingBolg

Comment: +1, but I don't think the @StackGaming account should be used.  An entirely new Twitter account just for the blog sounds great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an excellent idea. The account now tweets chat events, so I don't think there'll be a problem (at least non-technical) to do this.

We'll have to see what the team thinks about it, but +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

[image: StackGaming's tweet]

http://twitter.com/#!/StackGaming/status/90379387236646912

Comment: Yah!!! [15 chars]