# Can the blog contain links to the twitter accounts somewhere

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, blog, twitter

Can the [blog](https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/) contain a follow me or similar twitter link for the [@StackGaming twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/StackGaming) or the [proposed account from this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/twitter-account-for-gaming-blogoverflow-com) etc

i think it would be a neat addition and useful advertisement to people who visit the gaming blog.

In terms of display, it could/should sit under the follow on RSS link, or somewhere else on the left hand side. Not necessarily useful for people just visiting, but it may as well be listed on the [About page](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/about/) as well...

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The [Arqade Blog](https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/) has been deprecated and is only available in a read-only state for historical purposes. No features will be added at this stage.